# Открыть терминал по центру экрана ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash

есть баш скрипт, который вызывается из *.desktop файла, как я могу в этом файле разместить терминал, в котором открывается скрипт, по центру экрана?
Ниже desktop file, он просто вызывает скрипт, нужно его в окне как то по центру разместить, я нашел для gnome-terminal вот такие опции --geometry=123x42+0+0 но не могу их применить никак в данном случае, указывать как параметр не выходит...

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Name=name
    GenericName=name
    Comment=name
    Exec=/bin/startScript
    Terminal=true
    Icon=test
    Type=Application
    StartupNotify=true
    Categories=Network;
    MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;image/webp;x- 
    scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;
```

Comment: насколько мне известно, **в общем случае** — никак: расположением окон занимается программа класса *window manager* (таких программ — много). смотрите документацию к той программе, которая в вашей системе выполняет функции *window manager*-а. возможно, найдётся что-то полезное.

Comment: а ещё лучше привести конкретный desktop-файл... у многих конкретных эмуляторов терминала есть параметры позволяющие настроить их размер и положение на экране...

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

> Ниже desktop file, он просто вызывает скрипт, нужно его в окне как то по центру разместить, я нашел для gnome-terminal вот такие опции --geometry=123x42+0+0 но не могу их применить никак в данном случае, указывать как параметр не выходит...

Нужно вручную запускать конкретный эмулятор терминала, команда для экрана разрешением 1680x1050 будет примерно такая:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry=640x480+520+285 -e /bin/startScript
Terminal=false
```

О переносимости при таком подходе, само собой, придётся забыть.

Comment: спасибо, это работает.

Comment: @destr, если вопрос закрыт, то отметь правильным, чтоб не болтался...